# syntax error when running postgresql function/stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Trying to perform a set of complex Postgresql DB operations by using function, but even a simple function gets me error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "text"
LINE 3:    tmp text := info;
               ^
```

Here is SQL

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION createme (info text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
   tmp text := info;
BEGIN
   select :tmp
end
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

Any idea why?  Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You procedure is not in SQL language, but it is in plpgsql language.

```
CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION createme (info text) RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE 
  tmp text := info;
BEGIN
  RETURN tmp;
end
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`SELECT :tmp` is nonsense in this content. Functions returns a value with command `RETURN` - it is similar to any other environments.

Comment: Thanks @pavel-stehule !